# how to send email address via ajax using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var emailid='sample@email.com'
var data='email='+emailid;
    $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "sample.php",
               data: data,
               dataType: "text",
    });
```

i am sending emailid to server via ajax. whether i need to encode or decode email id while sending. Help me while sending email address via ajax how to encode and decode it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't pass a string to `data`; use an object and let jQuery handle the encoding:

```
var emailid = 'sample@email.com',
    data = { email: emailid };
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "sample.php",
           data: data,
           dataType: "text"
});
```

Note that I have removed the comma from after `dataType` so that your call will work in IE 6 & 7.

Comment: I actually didn't realise that jQuery does the encoding when you use an object for `data`. Removed my answer, voted this up.

Comment: @karim79 See [the jQuery AJAX source, line 666](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L666).

Comment: @karim79 I realise -- I put the link in because it's always fun to explore the jQuery source!